# precision values discared in intBitsTofloat in C

Tags: c, 64-bit, bit-manipulation

I have a double value =10.233387434223. I want to transmit it through network.
I convert this value to int32 bits by using
the following function

```
    int floatToRawIntBits(float_t  x)
{
  union {
    float_t f;  // assuming 32-bit IEEE 754 single-precision
    int32_t i;    // assuming 32-bit 2's complement int
        } u;

 u.f = x;
 return u.i;
}
```

and then  I try to get back this by using the function

```
union int_float_bits {
    int64_t int_bits;
  float_t float_bits;
};

float_t intBitsToFloat:(int64_t x)
{
    union int_float_bits bits;
    bits.int_bits = x;
    return bits.float_bits;
}
```

The output is : 10.233387 .
But I want to get back the original value 0f 10.233387434223 instead of 10.233387 .

intBitsToDouble may be a possible solution or not ?

I also try with these codes

```
int DoubleToRawIntBits(double_t  x)
{
    union {
        double_t f;
        int64_t i;
    } u;

    u.f = x;
    return u.i;
}
```

And

```
union int_double_bits {
    int64_t int_bits;
    double_t double_bits;
};
double_t intBitsToDouble(int64_t x)
{
    union int_double_bits bits;
    bits.int_bits = x;
    return bits.double_bits;
}
```

But here the result is 0.0000000.

Please help me ,Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use float anywhere if you want to preserve a double?  The moment you cast to float you lose the precision you want to retain.  Can't you just use double and 64 bit ints everywhere?

Comment: I use double instead of float everywhere throughout the code . But the result is 0.0000.

Comment: Can you show the code that results in 0.0000?

Comment: But the result 5.232444232211  is vary far from actual value 233387434223

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the first function returns only 32 bits out of a 64-bit double.  Only those 32 bits are transmitted.  Therefore, the next function can't construct the entire double because it literally does not have 32 bits of the double.  It can't pull that information out of nothing.  If it isn't there, it isn't there.  You need to transmit the entire double.  I don't know exactly what you're doing, but if you can send 32 bits across, you should also be able to send 64 bits.